# The sides AB,BC,CA lie on the lines 2y=x-4,x+y=5 and y=mx respectively. If the the origin O is the midpoint of AC , find the value of M

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

The sides AB,BC,CA lie on the lines 2y=x-4,x+y=5 and y=mx respectively. If the the origin O is the midpoint of AC , find the value of M
How can i find the coordinates of O if I don't know the coordinate of AC?

Comment: A is the intersection of the first two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $y=mx $ into $2y=x-4,\>x+y=5$ to get

$$ 2mx_1=x_1-4,\>\>\>\>\> x_2+mx_2=5$$

Given the midpoint is at origin, we have $x_1=-x_2$, which yields
$m=\frac32$.

Comment: what is x1=-x2? do you mean the midpoint formula or?

Comment: @Yoda - the midpoint formula (x1+x2)/2 = 0